# Unresolved reference WearableRecyclerView.Adapter error in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, wear-os, android-wear-2.0

I'm trying to create an android wear app with a list of items. To enable circular scrolling, I'm using [WearableRecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/ui/lists) by coding in kotlin. But facing this error **Unresolved reference: Adapter** The same code in java doesn't throw this error! I've also referred the inner and outer classes concepts in kotlin. Adapter class is an abstract class of RecyclerView which in turn is extended by WearableRecyclerView. Any guidance will be of much use, Thankyou!!

Here is my code

```
class CustomRecyclerAdapter(context: Context,dataSet: Array<String>): WearableRecyclerView.Adapter<CustomRecyclerAdapter.viewHolder>() {



var mDataSet: Array<String>
var mcontext: Context


init {
    mDataSet = dataSet
    mcontext=context
}

   inner class viewHolder(view: View) : WearableRecyclerView(mcontext) {

    val mTextView: TextView

    init {
        mTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.textView)
    }

    override fun toString(): String {
        return mTextView.text as String
    }
}

fun onCreateViewHolder(viewGroup: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): viewHolder {
    val view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.recycler_row_item, viewGroup, false)

    return viewHolder(view)
}

fun onBindViewHolder(viewHolder: viewHolder, position: Int) {
    // Replaces content of view with correct element from data set
    viewHolder.mTextView.text = mDataSet[position]
}

// Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return mDataSet.size
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using a (apparently non existent) `WearableRecyclerView.Adapter` consider using the non-wearable adapter: `RecyclerView.Adapter`

Answer (score 0):

Your class `inner class viewHolder(view: View) : WearableRecyclerView(mcontext)` must extends `WearableRecyclerView.ViewHolder` instead of `WearableRecyclerView` like :

```
inner class viewHolder(view: View) : WearableRecyclerView.ViewHolder(view)
```

Comment: If I add it likewise, I'm getting another similar error Unresolved reference: ViewHolder